# How can I get validate errors in json forman ? (Laravel,Fetch)

Tags: laravel, fetch-api

When I post request to controller by fetch it throws error (code 500).

How to make Controller processes properly my request ?

Request comes to Controller correctly because of if I'd typed in controller `echo json_encode("Hello")` I'd got answer in fetch.

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ExistEmailController extends Controller
{
        public function CheckingLogin(Request $req) {
        $rules = [
        'checkLogin' => 'required|min:5|max:50'
        ];
        $data = $req->checkLogin;
        $validatedData = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if($validatedData->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validatedData->messages(), 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Fetch-request

```
let data2 ;
let datasend ;
input_login.onblur = async () => {
  if(input_login.value != "")   {

    let checkLogin = input_login.value;
    let _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();

    let response = await fetch("/email-exist", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{"Content-Type":'application/json'},
        body:JSON.stringify({
            "_token":_token,
            "checkLogin":checkLogin
        })
    })
        datasend = await response.json();

        console.log(datasend)
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your code fails here

```
$data = $req->checkLogin;
$validatedData = Validator::make($data, $rules);
                                 ^^^^

The make() method accepts an array at its 1st argument
```

> Check out API Docs [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.html#method_make)

And try the following instead

```
//...
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
//...
```